Can I fetch data using React Server Components and 'use server' with just React.js v 18.2?
React Server Components and data fetching with React.
I am trying to use React Server Components and 'use server' with just React.js v 18.2 (not next.js 14)
If I use next.js 14 - Server Components and 'use server' seem to work as expected.
However - if I try to do the same in vanilla React.js v 18.2 (not next.js) - then 'use server' directive seems to have no effect.
If I do a console log in Next.js - the console.log shows in server terminal
export async function test() {
"use server";
console.log('test from server');
}

But if I do console log in vanilla React.js - the console.log shows in browser console
So do I understand things correctly - that React.js can't just use Server Components and 'use server' by itself and will need a framework like Next.js to take advantage of Server Components and 'use server'?
Also Regarding fetching data securely
Using next.js - we can securely fetch data.
Is there any way to fetch data securely with just React.js?
The Docs say:
'use server' can only be used in server-side files. The resulting Server Actions can be passed to Client Components through props.
https://react.dev/reference/rsc/use-server
Thanks Dave

they say it requires complicated bundler configurations, but don't really explain the details of that yet. this is still a bleeding edge feature that is under construction as far as I understand, and only Next.js has implemented it so far. https://react.dev/blog/2023/03/22/react-labs-what-we-have-been-working-on-march-2023#react-server-components
